# How to implement usercontrol to be visible on click inside one panel (DockPanel)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, user-controls, dockpanel

I am making a basic application in WPF (C#) where I wanted to use **UserControl**. I already created 3 sample UserControl and a single page window which have buttons, labels, panel etc. I wanted to load each UserControl on click button. You can see my logic (code) below -

```
    public partial class Dashboard : Window
{
    public Dashboard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Dock_MainPanel.Controls.Clear();
        Dock_MainPanel.Visible = true;
        Sample1 usr1 = new Sample1();
        usr1.Show();
        Dock_MainPanel.Controls.Add(usr1);
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //SAMPLE CODE
    }
}
```

Now my issue is this code is not working. It is stating some error. It is shown in image as below  -

[Error shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEPG8.png)

Basically I wanted to load each UserControl on clicking of their respective button. If anyone having other solutions, it is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Stefan W. suggests you should add an instance of the `UserControl` to the DockPanel's Children collection but if you intend to add several elements to the same `DockPanel` you probably also want to set the attached `Dock` property of the element using to specify where in the `DockPanel` the element will be located. You can do this using the `DockPanel.SetDock` method. Also, to make the `DockPanel` visible, you set its `Visibility` to `Visibility.Visible`. Try this:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dock_MainPanel.Children.Clear();
    Dock_MainPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Sample1 usr1 = new Sample1();
    DockPanel.SetDock(usr1, Dock.Right);
    Dock_MainPanel.Children.Add(usr1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should access the 'Children' collection in DockPanel

```
    Dock_MainPanel.Children.Clear();

    Dock_MainPanel.Children.Add(usr1);
```